# Number of photos: 0

Tags: photos, android-simple-facebook

Using SimpleFacebook to get photos after logging in it returns 0 photos.

I have 100+ photos..

#### Listener

```
OnPhotosListener onPhotosListener = new OnPhotosListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFail( String reason ) {
        Log.e( TAG, reason );
    }

    @Override
    public void onException( Throwable throwable ) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        Log.e( TAG, "Bad thing happened", throwable );
    }

    @Override
    public void onThinking() {
        showProgressDialog( "Getting facebook photos.." );
        Log.e( TAG, "Thinking..." );
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete( List<Photo> response ) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        Log.e( TAG, "Number of photos = " + response.size() );
        
        for ( Photo p : response ) {
            t( activity, "Photo id: " + p.getId() );
        }           
    }
};
```

#### And then

```
mSimpleFacebook.getPhotos( onPhotosListener );
```

#### Result

> Thinking...
> Number of photos = 0

#### Why?

Comment: I got the same error, did you able to find any solution?

Comment: @SkyWalker no, I skipped the whole thing.